# Podcast Best Practices - Page Development & Monetization Considerations

Tags: web-development, best-practices, audio, monetize, podcast

Our current podcast page has show notes and a link to download an mp3 of our podcast.  We were advised to add an audio player to stream the file live from our website.  The thought being this would improve time spent on our site and allow for greater advertising dollars.

Is it better to have a page with show notes, an mp3 for download AND also stream the podcast live
OR
just stick to the show notes & mp3 download?

Does anyone see any affect on advertising revenue, either way?

Answer (score 0):

If you stream live then you will need the bandwidth resources, you should also try polling your listeners to see which they prefer. If you are going to stream live then your audience will rely on you to be prompt, stream on time every time. I've seen some live streams that also includes an embedded chat room so listeners can interact with the host during the live stream. If you are going to stream live you may also want to consider a break out window, so users can continue to browse without losing the page/window. You may also want to develop a mobile app for smartphone listeners as well. Streaming live can definitely increase your income, but it can be costly as well. Options include using services like Live 365 to stream and so forth.